# Problem with LINQ query: Select first task from each goal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm looking for suggestions on how to write a query. For each `Goal`, I want to select the first `Task` (sorted by `Task.Sequence`), in addition to any tasks with `ShowAlways == true`. (My actual query is more complex, but this query demonstrates the limitations I'm running into.)

I tried something like this:

```
var tasks = (from a in DbContext.Areas
             from g in a.Goals
             from t in g.Tasks
             let nextTaskId = g.Tasks.OrderBy(tt => tt.Sequence).Select(tt => tt.Id).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).FirstOrDefault()
             where t.ShowAlways || t.Id == nextTaskId
             select new CalendarTask
             {

                 // Member assignment

             }).ToList();
```

But this query appears to be too complex.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression 'OrderBy<Task, int>(
    source: MaterializeCollectionNavigation(Navigation: Goal.Tasks(< Tasks > k__BackingField, DbSet<Task>) Collection ToDependent Task Inverse: Goal, Where<Task>(
        source: NavigationExpansionExpression
            Source: Where<Task>(
                source: DbSet<Task>,
                predicate: (t0) => Property<Nullable<int>>((Unhandled parameter: ti0).Outer.Inner, "Id") == Property<Nullable<int>>(t0, "GoalId"))
            PendingSelector: (t0) => NavigationTreeExpression
                Value: EntityReferenceTask
                Expression: t0
        ,
        predicate: (i) => Property<Nullable<int>>(NavigationTreeExpression
            Value: EntityReferenceGoal
            Expression: (Unhandled parameter: ti0).Outer.Inner, "Id") == Property<Nullable<int>>(i, "GoalId"))), 
    keySelector: (tt) => tt.Sequence)' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.'
```

The problem is the line `let nextTaskId =...`. If I comment out that, there is no error. (But I don't get what I'm after.)

I'll readily admit that I don't understand the details of the error message. About the only other way I can think of to approach this is return all the `Task`s and then sort and filter them on the client. But my preference is not to retrieve data I don't need.

Can anyone see any other ways to approach this query?

*Note: I'm using the very latest version of Visual Studio and .NET.*

**UPDATE:**

I tried a different, but less efficient approach to this query.

```
var tasks = (DbContext.Areas
      .Where(a => a.UserId == UserManager.GetUserId(User) && !a.OnHold)
      .SelectMany(a => a.Goals)
      .Where(g => !g.OnHold)
      .Select(g => g.Tasks.Where(tt => !tt.OnHold && !tt.Completed).OrderBy(tt => tt.Sequence).FirstOrDefault()))
    .Union(DbContext.Areas
      .Where(a => a.UserId == UserManager.GetUserId(User) && !a.OnHold)
      .SelectMany(a => a.Goals)
      .Where(g => !g.OnHold)
      .Select(g => g.Tasks.Where(tt => !tt.OnHold && !tt.Completed && (tt.DueDate.HasValue || tt.AlwaysShow)).OrderBy(tt => tt.Sequence).FirstOrDefault()))
    .Distinct()
    .Select(t => new CalendarTask
    {
        Id = t.Id,
        Title = t.Title,
        Goal = t.Goal.Title,
        CssClass = t.Goal.Area.CssClass,
        DueDate = t.DueDate,
        Completed = t.Completed
    });
```

But this also produced an error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Processing of the LINQ expression 'Where<Task>(
    source: MaterializeCollectionNavigation(Navigation: Goal.Tasks (<Tasks>k__BackingField, DbSet<Task>) Collection ToDependent Task Inverse: Goal, Where<Task>(
        source: NavigationExpansionExpression
            Source: Where<Task>(
                source: DbSet<Task>, 
                predicate: (t) => Property<Nullable<int>>((Unhandled parameter: ti).Inner, "Id") == Property<Nullable<int>>(t, "GoalId"))
            PendingSelector: (t) => NavigationTreeExpression
                Value: EntityReferenceTask
                Expression: t
        , 
        predicate: (i) => Property<Nullable<int>>(NavigationTreeExpression
            Value: EntityReferenceGoal
            Expression: (Unhandled parameter: ti).Inner, "Id") == Property<Nullable<int>>(i, "GoalId"))), 
    predicate: (tt) => !(tt.OnHold) && !(tt.Completed))' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.'
```

Comment: I am slightly confused by `t in g.Tasks` and `t => t.Sequence`, but that's not probably the issue. Well, have you tried to rewrite this query using method syntax (`DbContext.Areas.SelectMany(area => area.Goals.Select(goal => new { goal, area }).SelectMany`? It may make some difference depending on how exactly the current query is being translated into Queryable extension method calls. Also you may try to select all possible {group, area, task}, group them and only then `where t.ShowAlways || t.Id == nextTaskId` //.

Comment: may be try DbContext.Tasks.Where(t => t.GoalId != null).GroupBy(g =>g.GoalId)...

Comment: @EugenePodskal: You didn't articulate what you were slightly confused about. `g` (Group) has a one to many relation ship to Tasks, and `t` (Task) has a `Sequence` column. I'm not seeing how your replacement query gets the tasks I'm interested. Using `SelectMany()` should be the same as `from a in DbContext.Areas from g in a.Goals from t in g.Tasks`.

Comment: @Matt.G: I'm not sure how that could be used to filter the tasks how I need.

Comment: I'm confused by the fact that we have `t` meaning two different things in basically the same scope, though it seems to compile for you. And yes, `SelectMany() should be the same`, but that doesn't mean that it will - it is at least worth a try.

Comment: @EugenePodskal: Oh, you mean that I use the same symbol? Well, that was part that I tweaked for my example. `t` in the Lambda expressions should probably be something else.

Comment: @JonathanWood try rewriting the `nextTaskId` for example: `g.Tasks.OrderBy(tt => tt.Sequence).Min(tt => tt.Id)` or `g.Tasks.OrderBy(tt => tt.Sequence).FirstOrDefault().Id`

Comment: @jcruz: I tried `g.Tasks.Min(tt => tt.Sequence)`. (No reason for `OrderBy` here.) But get the same error.

Comment: @JonathanWood, this is what I meant: `var tasks = DbContext.Tasks.Where(x => x.GoalId != null)
                   .GroupBy(x => x.GoalId)
                   .SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.ShowAlways || y.Id == x.OrderBy(z => z.Sequence).First().Id));`

Comment: @JonathanWood the error is a bit obscure. Maybe instantiating a `new CalendarTask` is where the issue is. Try moving the `ToList()` call before your `select`

Comment: @jcruz: The error is the line where I set `nextTaskId`. Commenting out that line eliminates the error.

Comment: @JonathanWood in that case have you tried applying the nextTaskId logic right in the where clause? example: `where t.ShowAlways || t.Id == g.Tasks.Min(tt => tt.Sequence)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have EF Core up and running, but are you able to split it up like this?

```
    var allTasks = DbContext.Areas
        .SelectMany(a => a.Goals)
        .SelectMany(a => a.Tasks);

    var always = allTasks.Where(t => t.ShowAlways);

    var next = allTasks
        .OrderBy(tt => tt.Sequence)
        .Take(1);

    var result = always
        .Concat(next)
        .Select(t => new
         {
             // Member assignment
         })
        .ToList();
```

Edit: Sorry, I'm not great with query syntax, maybe this does what you need?

```
    var allGoals = DbContext.Areas
        .SelectMany(a => a.Goals);

    var allTasks = DbContext.Areas
        .SelectMany(a => a.Goals)
        .SelectMany(a => a.Tasks);

    var always = allGoals
        .SelectMany(a => a.Tasks)
        .Where(t => t.ShowAlways);

    var nextTasks = allGoals
        .SelectMany(g => g.Tasks.OrderBy(tt => tt.Sequence).Take(1));

    var result = always
        .Concat(nextTasks)
        .Select(t => new
         {
             // Member assignment
         })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: So, this does run without errors and is interesting. But the logic isn't quite the same. I need the next task for each goal. This only returns the next task for all areas and goals.

Comment: @JonathanWood ah ok, I've updated my answer, maybe that's more like what you wanted? Again, I'm not sure if EF Core can cope with it, I'm setting one up locally now to test it.

Comment: I was able to get the second version working and it appears to be right. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good example for the need of full reproducible example. When trying to reproduce the issue with similar entity models, I was either getting a different error about `DefaulIfEmpty(-1)` (apparently not supported, don't forget to remove it - the SQL query will work correctly w/o it) or no error when removing it.

Then I noticed a small deeply hidden difference in your error messages compared to mine, which led me to the cause of the problem:

```
MaterializeCollectionNavigation(Navigation: Goal.Tasks (<Tasks>k__BackingField, DbSet<Task>)
```

specifically the `DbSet<Task>` at the end (in my case it was `ICollection<Task>`). I realized that you used `DbSet<T>` type for collection navigation property rather than the usual `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `List<T>` etc., e.g.

```
public class Goal
{
    // ...
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Simply don't do that. `DbSet<T>` is a special EF Core class, supposed to be used only from `DbContext` to represent db table, view or raw SQL query result set. And more importantly, `DbSet`s are the only real EF Core query *roots*, so it's not surprising that such usage confuses the EF Core query translator.

So change it to some of the supported interfaces/classes (for instance,  `ICollection<Task>`) and the original problem will be solved.

Then removing the `DefaultIfEmpty(-1)` will allow successfully translating the first query in question.

Comment: I appreciate the insightful answer. I changed my custom models to use `ICollection<>` for foreign key fields instead of `DbSet<>`. Unfortunately, I still get a similar error.

Comment: Similar, but different (what is the new message)? Anyway, unfortunately the cause of the non translatable EF Core queries is inside concrete details. Without concrete error and repro (exact entity model, configuration and query + EF Core version because translation/bugs/limitations differ even between minor versions) there is nothing more we can do to help solving the concrete issue (I was quite lucky to notice that `DbSet<>` thing).

Comment: At a glance, the error looks exactly the same. But you saw that I was using DbSet in the first error so I assume at least that changed. I indicated I'm using the latest version (although today there's an update). Seems to me the query is just too complex for current version of Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you start by breaking up this query into individual parts. Try iterating through the `Goals` in a `foreach` with your `Task` logic inside. Add each new `CalendarTask` to a List that you defined ahead of time.

Overall breaking this logic up and experimenting a bit will probably lead you to some insight with the limitations of Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Iterating through the goals in a `foreach` would first retrieve them all of them from the database. Then, to get each related task would either require lazy loading, which means I'd have a separate trip to the database for each and every task, or preloading every task in a single query. In the first case, performance would be severely impacted with all those round trips to the database. In the second case, I am bringing over a bunch of data that I don't need, which as I pointed out in the question, is something I would prefer not to do.

Comment: If Task is its own DbSet you could select all tasks with `ShowAlways` in a different query. That way your logic is only looking for the first in the sequence. Then just union the results. There may be nothing that you can do to be super efficient without stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I think we might separate the query into two steps. First, query each goals and get the min Sequence task and store them(maybe with a anonymous type like {NextTaskId,Goal}). Then, we query the temp data and get the result. For example

```
Areas.SelectMany(x=>x.Goals)
    .Select(g=>new {
        NextTaskId=g.Tasks.OrderBy(t=>t.Sequence).FirstOrDefault()?.Id,
        Tasks=g.Tasks.Where(t=>t.ShowAlways)
      })
    .SelectMany(a=>a.Tasks,(a,task)=>new {
            NextTaskId = a.NextTaskId,
            Task = task
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create the linq request but I'm not sure about the result

```cs
        var tasks =   ( from a in DbContext.Areas
                        from g in a.Goals
                        from t in g.Tasks 
                            join oneTask in (from  t in DbContext.Tasks
                            group t by t.Id into gt
                            select new {
                                  Id = gt.Key,
                                  Sequence = gt.Min(t => t.Sequence)
                              }) on  new { t.Id, t.Sequence } equals  new { oneTask.Id,oneTask.Sequence }
                            select new {Area = a, Goal = g, Task = t})
                        .Union(         
                        from a in DbContext.Areas
                        from g in a.Goals
                        from t in g.Tasks 
                            where t.ShowAlways 
                            select new {Area = a, Goal = g, Task = t});
```

Answer (score 0):

I currently don't have EF Core, but do you really need to compare this much?

Wouldn't querying the tasks be sufficient?

If there is a navigation property or foreign key defined I could imaging using something like this:

`Tasks.Where(task => task.Sequence == Tasks.Where(t => t.GoalIdentity == task.GoalIdentity).Min(t => t.Sequence) || task.ShowAlways);`

Comment: No, that doesn't come close to what I need.